# How to execute the BDD file without using a JUnit runner class file?

Tags: testing, junit, junit4, bdd

It is possible to run **BDD** feature file without using **runner class**? If yes, How?

Comment: What BDD tools are you looking at - Cucumber, JBehave, etc.? And what context are you running them in? Are you trying to replace the runner for a whole suite through Gradle? Are you looking to run one test with IntelliJ? Why do you want to get rid of the test runner? Without more information about what you're trying to do, the answer is, yes, but you'd have to rewrite the capabilities of whatever runner you're replacing yourself.

Answer (score 1):

I don’t think it is possible to use without runner class, unless you modify the way cucumber is called.

I created NoCodeBDD precisely for this reason. You don’t need any project set up or coding to automate BDDs. You can download a free version from [www.nocodebdd.com/download](https://www.nocodebdd.com/download). I would like to get some feedback from you and from the stackoverflow community